# "sLaravel" instead of "Laravel" in console messages

Tags: laravel-5

Did anyone encounter this problem? Can you please help me how to resolve this problem that we encounter. When we try to serve our application we notice the message has "S" in the beginning, and the UI has also S in the upper right corner.

[image]

Comment: check line 46 in file /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Iluminate/Fundation/Console/ServeCommand.php or better try update you laravel using command composer update

Comment: Thnx for the reply.. we already fixed the problem sir. it was in the routes.php instead of 
<?php
...
?> it has  s in the beginning of  "**s<?php ...?>**"

Comment: Hahaha nice guys i will be remember that in future :)

Answer (score 0):

In our case. we check the **routes.php** and we notice that there is s in the beginning of the "php tag".

```
s<?php
 ...
 ...
?>
```

instead of

```
<?php
 ...
 ...
?>
```